# Modifying a function from a package in Julia

Tags: julia

First I'm sorry if this question seems vague, because I'm new to Julia and I'm mostly just wondering in Julia if there's an easy way to modify a native function of a package while simply using all its dependencies in general, or there has to be a package-specific solution.

For example, foo is a function from the package LibraryA, and it can be simply called and used as follows without problem:

```
using LibraryA 

foo(args)
```

However, if I want a slightly modified version of foo(), say bar(), whose source code (mostly copy of the foo() function) is in a separate file bar.jl and uses a lot of dependencies from LibraryA, the lines

```
using LibraryA 

include("bar.jl")
bar(args)
```

will not work as lots of loaderrors occur:

```
LoadError: UndefVarError: vars not defined
```

where vars are the variables defined in the package LibraryA

Comment: You can also just write `LibraryA.vars`

Answer (score 5):

As long as the variables are in the global scope in `LibraryA`, you can import them explicitly to make them available in the current scope:

```
using LibraryA: vars, bigvar, littlevar, baz

include("bar.jl")
bar(args)
```

As a matter of convention, however, make sure that these variables are not intended to be "private" i.e. intended for internal use in LibraryA (there's no explicit *private* marker in Julia, it's generally inferred based on documentation).

If a variable `vars` itself appears to be private, but has an accessor `getvars` that's public, you can instead create a new variable `vars` in the current scope using that accessor.

```
using LibraryA: bigvar, littlevar, baz, getvars

vars = getvars()

include("bar.jl")
bar(args)
```

(Make sure to make it a `const var` if it was `const` originally, and similarly type annotate it `var::WhateverTheTypeOfVarIs` if it is annotated in the original module as well.)

Comment: Thanks. This indeed works.
I suppose because even thought my bar() function looks similar to foo(), since it is no longer in the 'header' file (or something similar) of the original package, I have to explicitly include anything that the functions uses